# Isolate strings from CSV and print them

Tags: python, csv

### Question:

This is a small part in a bigger project. I'd like to believe I'm good at understanding delimiters and CSVs but I don't know what to do or what to ask.

Dumb question, how can I isolate the strings from this list and print them?

```
(0, 'img_10.jpg')
(1, 'img_8.mp4')
(2, 'img_31.mp4')
(3, 'img_30.mp4')
(4, 'img_9.mp4')
(5, 'img_12.jpg')
(6, 'img_20.mp4')
(7, '.DS_Store')
(8, 'img_21.mp4')
(9, 'img_35.mp4')
```

### Desired output:

```
'img_10.jpg'
'img_8.mp4'
'img_31.mp4'
'img_30.mp4'
'img_9.mp4'
'img_12.jpg'
'img_20.mp4'
'.DS_Store'
'img_21.mp4'
'img_35.mp4'
```

### My script below:

```
import glob, os
import sys
import csv

folder_path = "path"
list = os.listdir(folder_path)

with open("files.txt", "w", newline='\n', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    i = 0
    for file in enumerate(list):
        csvfile.write(str(file) + "\n")
        print(file)
```

Comment: removed pandas tag, because no pandas code.

Comment: The rsal problem was enunerate not tuple, the redirection is incorrect

Comment: if an answer solves your problem, make it  as answer to appreciate them thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't enummerate use list iterator
When you enumerate the list it will give index and the element as tuple that's why you got `(i,element)` tuple. If you don't need indexes then you can only iterate the list elements.

**Using `list` as a varaible name is not a good practice because it is a python keyword**

```
folder_path = "path"
list_files = os.listdir(folder_path)

with open("files.txt", "w", newline='\n', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    i = 0
    for file in list_files:
        csvfile.write(str(file) + "\n")
        print(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are enumerating, you are saving also the index on your `file` variable, making it a tuple. `file[1]` should do the job on your case. If you really need the enumerator, I suggest to separate it on another variable.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `enumerate` you are looping through tuples that includes a index for each element you have in the list.. u better remove it and your code should work fine:

```
import glob, os
import sys
import csv

folder_path = "path"
list_ = os.listdir(folder_path)

with open("files.txt", "w", newline='\n', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        i = 0
        for file in list_:
            csvfile.write(str(file) + "\n")
        print(file)
```